# SMS using twilio from mobile app not working

Tags: gradle, twilio

As per the guidelines in [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html).

I've completed everything. But it's not working. No errors are occurring. I don't know where to check for the issues. Please can someone help me with a solution or at least where to look for issues?

Please find below manifest file

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
            package="uhnm.stroke.strokeapp_secondscreen">

            <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

                <activity android:name=".NIHSSActivityPage4" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
                <activity android:name=".TeamsDisplay" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
                <activity android:name=".imageActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
                <activity android:name=".timesActivity" />
                <activity android:name=".configurationActivity" />
                <activity android:name=".addConsultants" />
                <activity android:name=".NIHSSActivityFinalPage"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
                <activity android:name=".NIHSSActivityPage3" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
                <activity android:name=".NIHSSActivityPage2" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
                <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
                <activity android:name=".EnterBrainTracker" />
                <activity android:name=".NIHSSActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
                <activity
                    android:name=".signIn"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <service
                        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
                        android:exported="false">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                     </intent-filter>
                    </service>

                    <meta-data
                            android:name="strokeapp.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
                    </application>

            </manifest>
```

Here the app gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {

     compileSdkVersion 29

     buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

        //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {

            applicationId "uhnm.stroke.strokeapp_secondscreen"

            minSdkVersion 16

            targetSdkVersion 29

            versionCode 1

            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

            multiDexEnabled true

        }

        buildTypes {

             release {

                    minifyEnabled false

                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            }

        }

        packagingOptions

            {

                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

            }

}

dependencies {

        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
        implementation group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "7.44.0"
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1'
}
```

Comment: We need to find where the error is occurring. Can you tell whether your server URL gets called by the Android application (and thus the problem is in your server side code)? Or is the issue in the Android application before it tries to make the request to your server?

Comment: Thanks PhilNash for your reply. I will close this thread as I have implemented push notification using fcm. Thanks and apologies for not closing this